# Unable to load thrift_native extension. Defaulting to pure Ruby libraries

Tags: ruby, libraries, thrift

when I execute a ruby code I get

```
 Unable to load thrift_native extension. Defaulting to pure Ruby libraries.
```

how I ignore this message ?

Comment: You don't. You fix the problem.

Comment: can you show some code, and get us around what you are trying to achieve? :)

Comment: Any solution yet on this ?

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Ruby warning message and you just don't want to see it, this should answer your question.

[How to disable warning for redefining a constant when loading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236264/how-to-disable-warning-for-redefining-a-constant-when-loading-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jruby.

I got rid of this warning by adding an empty file named 'thrift_native.rb' to a directory in my $LOAD_PATH that takes precedence over the thrift folder.

I Chose to simply add it in the same 'app-root' directory that my Gemfile is stored in.