# How to disable warning for redefining a constant when loading a file

Tags: ruby, warnings, constants, suppress-warnings

Is there a way to disable `warning: already initialized constant` when loading particular files?

Comment: Is fixing the code really out of the question?

Comment: Warnings are often indicative of non-fatal **errors**, and should be fixed. In this case you do very possibly have a real problem that should be fixed.

Comment: you initialized your variable more than once.

Comment: @DmitrySavy Yes. That's right. But that does not answer my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redefine a Ruby constant without warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375360/how-to-redefine-a-ruby-constant-without-warning)

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks. I think your link tells my what I need to do. But still, I would like to do it without using special methods mentioned there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To suppress warnings, use the following code at the top of the script:

```
$VERBOSE = nil
```

Comment: This one is the most useful for other people in the broader context, because Constant redefinition is only one thing that can trigger non-fatal compilation warnings. It's all very well suggesting you fix your code, but that presumes the thing triggering this is in your code and not something  in an upstream library.

Comment: yes, that works, but silencing *all* warnings is maybe not the best in production

Answer (score 49):

The solution to your problem depends on what is causing it.

1 - You are changing the value of a constant that was set before somewhere in your code, or are trying to define a constant with the same name as an existant class or module. Solution: don't use constants if you know in advance that the value of the constant will change; don't define constants with the same name as class/modules.

2 - You are in a situation where you want to redefine a constant for good reasons, without getting warnings. There are two options.

First, you could undefine the constant before redefining it (this requires a helper method, because `remove_const` is a private function):

```
Object.module_eval do
  # Unset a constant without private access.
  def self.const_unset(const)
    self.instance_eval { remove_const(const) }
  end
end
```

Or, you could just tell the Ruby interpreter to shut up (this suppresses *all* warnings):

```
# Runs a block of code without warnings.
def silence_warnings(&block)
  warn_level = $VERBOSE
  $VERBOSE = nil
  result = block.call
  $VERBOSE = warn_level
  result
end
```

3 - You are requiring an external library that defines a class/module whose name clashes with a new constant or class/module you are creating. Solution: wrap your code inside a top-level module-namespace to prevent the name clash.

```
class SomeClass; end
module SomeModule
   SomeClass = '...' 
end
```

4 - Same as above, but you absolutely need to define a class with the same name as the gem/library's class. Solution: you can assign the library's class name to a variable, and then clear it for your later use:

```
require 'clashing_library'
some_class_alias = SomeClass
SomeClass = nil
# You can now define your own class:
class SomeClass; end
# Or your own constant:
SomeClass = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 31):

Try this :

```
Kernel::silence_warnings { MY_CONSTANT = 'my value '}
```

Comment: This method doesn’t exist with Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: It's a part of rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-silence_warnings

Comment: Excellent solution, It's part of rails, but you can just import the 2 methods `silence_warnings` and `with_warnings` in a file of your choice and patch `Kernel` with it.

Comment: If you are using Rails, this is probably what you want.

Comment: And you can use it without `Kernel::` prefix, it'll be even shorter then!

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890939) was helpful. I looked at the Rails source to get the following. Before and after loading the file, I can insert these lines:

```
# Supress warning messages.
original_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil
    load(file_in_question)
# Activate warning messages again.
$VERBOSE = original_verbose
```

Comment: that worked. I should probably write a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [user2398029's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9236572/5372951) the simplest way for me to remove warnings was to add this line:

```rb
before { described_class.instance_eval { remove_const(:CONSTANT_NAME) } }
```